# Example of regular Borel measure which is not a Radon measure

Tags: measure-theory

Are there any non-trivial examples of regular Borel measures which are not Radon measures?

**ADDED LATER:** I wasn't aware of the many disparate definitions for these notions. Here I mean:

regular: inner regular on compacts, outer regular on open sets
Radon: regular Borel measure which is finite on compacts

Comment: What are your trivial examples?

Comment: I was thinking of the measure assigning $\infty$ to the non-empty compact sets (of, say, the real line) and $0$ to $\phi$.

Comment: Consider any bounded family $\{x_n\}_{n \in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb R^d$. Think of a measure concentrated on $\{x_n\}$. What wages should one give to each $x_n$, to make that measure infinite on some compacts sets of $\mathbb R^d$.

Comment: There are several definitions of regular measure and Radon measure. Specify exactly which ones you mean (inner regular for compacta, locally finite, $\sigma$-finite, outer regular for opens etc etc.) Any conditions on the space?

Comment: @DominikKutek surprisingly simple, thank you! I guess the plethora of definitions got me a bit confused ^^

Comment: @HennoBrandsma in my book, regular = inner regular on compact, outer regular on open sets and Radon = finite on compact sets (i.e. locally finite).

Comment: @othi add it to the body of the question please. It makes it more self-contained. Radom does not imply regular in any form?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma done! No I meant in addition to regular, clarified in question now!

Comment: Indiscrete space with $\mu(\emptyset)=0$ and $\mu(X)= +\infty$ e.g.

Answer (score 2):

In Exercise 2 of §25 in [1] the following example is given: Equip $\mathbb R$ with the Sorgenfrey topology ${\cal O}_\tau$, that is, $U\in{\cal O}_\tau$ iff for every $x\in U$ there is an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $[x,x+\varepsilon[\subset U\,.$ Then,

(a) every interval $[a,b[$ with $a<b$ is closed and open at the same time. The topology ${\cal O}_\tau$ is strictly finer than the usual topology of $\mathbb R$. In particular $(\mathbb R,{\cal O}_\tau)$ is a Hausdorff space.

(b) The Borel $\sigma$-algebra of $(\mathbb R,{\cal O}_\tau)$ is identical to the usual Borel sigma algebra of $\mathbb R\,.$

...

(f) Let $\mu$ be the measure on the Borel $\sigma$-algebra that assigns zero to every countable set and $+\infty$ to every uncountable set. This is a Borel measure that is not locally finite and neither regular from inside nor from outside.

[1] H. Bauer, *Measure and Integration Theory*. De Gruyter, Berlin New York 2001.

Comment: This is not an example as asked: **regular** but not Radon. Your space can hardly have a regular measure for compacta as compacta are at most countable.

Comment: Sorry. You are right. OP asked regular Borel but not Radon. Perhaps Bauer's Lemma 25.3 then helps : *Let $E$ be a Hausdorff-space $E$ where every point has a countable basis (of neighborhoods). Then every Borel measure on $E$ that is regular from inside is locally finite and thus a Radon measure.*

Answer (score 0):

Take $\Bbb R$ in the cofinite topology. The Borel algebra is the countable co-countable one. Give the former sets measure $0$ and the latter ones measure $+\infty$.

Comment: It would be great if you can clarify your answer or providing citation, since "cofinite topology" is not familiar.